# How to add to array if no response during 1 second?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have an intercept that listens requests/responses.

I have tried to run spinner only if requests comes more then 1 seconds:

```
 @Injectable()
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private requests: HttpRequest<any>[] = [];

  constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.requests.push(req);
    this.spinnerService.isLoading.next(true);

    return new Observable((observer) => {
      next.handle(req).subscribe(
        (event) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.removeRequest(req);
            observer.next(event);
          }
        },
        () => {
          this.removeRequest(req);
        },
        () => {
          this.removeRequest(req);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  private removeRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    const index = this.requests.indexOf(request);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.requests.splice(index, 1);
    }

    this.spinnerService.loadingStop.next();
    this.spinnerService.loadingStop.complete();
    this.spinnerService.isLoading.next(this.requests.length > 0);
  }
}
```

Spinner service is:

```
 constructor() {
    this.isLoading
      .pipe(debounceTime(100), delay(1000), takeUntil(this.loadingStop))
      .subscribe((status: boolean) => (this.loadingStatus = status));
  }
```

For that I have added this:

```
.pipe(debounceTime(100), delay(1000), takeUntil(this.loadingStop))
```

But it does not work for me...How to show spinner if response comes more 1 second?

Comment: try using `timeout` instead of `delay`

Comment: Logic is right? When I get resposne I do `stop$`

Comment: Timeout without takeUntil?

Comment: Timeout gives me exception in console: `TimeoutErrorImpl {message: "Timeout has occurred", name: "TimeoutError"}`

Comment: what was your code for `timeout`?

Comment: I was waiting for your reply, pelase do let me know if you need help to solve this :)

Comment: My code is: `this.isLoading
      .pipe(debounceTime(100), timeout(1000), takeUntil(this.loadingStop))
      .subscribe((status: boolean) => (this.loadingStatus = status));`.  It does not work

Comment: Anybode else can help me?

Comment: Problem is that it is blinking if I get fast response

Comment: To get rid of the blinking, try something like this, it will ensure that if the spinner is displayed it stays visible for at least 1 second. `this.isLoading
      .pipe(debounceTime(1000), takeUntil(this.loadingStop.pipe(debounceTime(1000))
      .subscribe((status: boolean) => (this.loadingStatus = status));`

Comment: Are you sure? Because each time when elemnet is removed from array it again sends message here if length > 0:  `this.spinnerService.isLoading.next(this.requests.length > 0);`

Comment: So, I need run spinner only if there is delay from server after 1 second

Comment: Your advice does not stop spinner using

Comment: Also it does not work if I want run spinenr immidiatly, it has delay

Comment: can you try and simplify your example and ask a specific question?

Comment: @Jessy your timeout value is 1 milli second so it might blink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses the iif operator to stop loading instantly.

this is what the interceptor should look like:

```
constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  this.spinnerService.start(request.url);

  return next.handle(request).pipe(
    finalize(() => () => this.spinnerService.stop(request.url))
  );
}
```

this is the loading service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
  private _loading: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  private _request: Set<string>;
  private _delayTime: number;

  constructor() {
    this._loading = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    this._request = new Set();
    this._delayTime = 1000;
  }

  isLoading(time?: number): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._loading.asObservable().pipe(
      // uses switchMap to cancel the previous event
      switchMap(isLoading =>
        // use iif to put delay only for true value
        iif(
          () => isLoading,
          of(isLoading).pipe(
            delay(time !== undefined ? time : this._delayTime),
          ),
          of(isLoading),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  start(request: string = 'default', delayTime?: number): void {
    if (delayTime !== undefined)
      this._delayTime = delayTime;

    this._request.add(request);
    this._loading.next(true);
  }

  stop(request: string = 'default'): void {
    this._request.delete(request);

    if (!this._request.size)
      this._loading.next(false);
  }
}
```

and so it should look in the template

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div *ngIf="isLoading$ | async">loading...</div>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isLoading$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) {
    this.isLoading$ = this.spinnerService.isLoading();
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean? `switchMap(isLoading => iif()` Why you switching?

Comment: And what is it i`ff()`?

Comment: make a switchMap to stop the previous event

Comment: and iif you use to set delay only for true value

Comment: It means `get isLoading()` calling from template, right?

Comment: you don't need a push/remove

Comment: @Jessy I made changes to take all requests in consideration

Comment: So, now I dont need count request in inteeception,, only start/stop?

Comment: And how to start it without delay, if I wish?

Comment: No I can not run/stop spinner without no delay, it always invokes

Comment: I have tedted your code. it does not run loader after 1 seconds and more

Comment: Immidialty I get success `tap()` despite server not returned data

Comment: @Jessy it is not possible, the data reaches in the tap after the request has ended

Comment: I fixed, but there is another problem when request is cancelled spinner still twists

Comment: How to `stop()` if request was canceled?

Comment: how is it canceled?

Comment: I have tried to add: ` finalize(() => {
        this.spinnerService.stop();
      })` for  `next.handle(request).pipe()` but it somethins does not stop spinner

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the flickering of the loading indicator (I omitted the handling of multiple requests).

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.spinnerService.start();
    return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize( () => this.spinnerService.stop()));
  }
}
```

**debounceTime(500)** in spinner service does the trick:

```
export class SpinnerService {

  private readonly state = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  readonly state$ = this.state.asObservable()
    .pipe(
       debounceTime(500), 
       distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  constructor() {}

  public start() {
    this.state.next(true);
  }

  public stop() {
    this.state.next(false);
  }
}
```

The component to see this in action:

```
export interface Post {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css'],
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
  readonly posts$: Observable<Post[]> = this.httpClient
    .get<Post[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .pipe(shareReplay(1));

  readonly state$ = this.spinnerService.state$;

  constructor(
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService,
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>List of Posts</p>

<ng-container *ngIf="(state$ | async);  else printResult">
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #printResult>
  <ng-container *ngIf="posts$ | async as posts">
    <p *ngFor="let post of posts">
      {{ post.title }}
    </p>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

The solution via an interceptor is somewhat coarse grained. At some point you might need a finer grained solution. E.g. to show a loading indicator for multiple parallel requests/components. Another solution is given in [Nil's blog post](https://nils-mehlhorn.de/posts/indicating-loading-the-right-way-in-angular).

There are plenty solutions to your problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: your loader will stop 500 ms after all requests have been ended