# Angular: Display a loader/spinner overlay with a service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am currently working on a Angular 8 project, and I'm currently working on a feature that I think a lot of projects use. I want to display a spinner when something is loading in the app, with a gray background so you can't interact with the app during the loading time.

I found some examples on the Internet, but most of them use Interceptors, in order to display an overlay everytime an http call is in progress. This is not possible in my case, as some http calls should not block the use of the app.

So, I took inspiration from a package I already used : Angular2-notifications.

- I created a LoaderService, just with start() and end() methods. These can be called anywhere in the application
- I created a LoaderComponent, that I put in the app.component.html, and displays this overlay whenever the LoaderService tells it to.

My main problem here is the synchronization if I have multiple requests for a loader.
For example, I have a screen with multiple tabs, and some of them load their own content. This is not a lazy loading case, all data are loaded at the init of the screen. So, each of these tabs will ask to display a spinner at the same moment.

My solution right now is that LoaderService.start() returns a token, and when the call is done, you have to call LoadService.end(myToken) in order to hide the spinner. In the service, I keep an array of all current tokens in use, and the spinner is displayed when this array.length > 0.

The code right here :
LoaderService :

```
@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {

  private currentIndex = 0;
  private currentLoaderIds: number[] = [];

  public emitter = new Subject<boolean>();

  start(): number {
    this.currentIndex++;
    this.currentLoaderIds.push(this.currentIndex);
    this.emitter.next(true);
    return this.currentIndex;
  }

  end(id?: number): void {
    if (!id) {
      return;
    }
    this.currentLoaderIds = this.currentLoaderIds.filter(i => i !== id);
    if (this.currentLoaderIds.length === 0) {
      this.emitter.next(false);
    }
  }
}
```

LoaderComponent

```
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private show = false;
  private listener: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private loader: LoaderService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listener = this.loader.emitter
      .subscribe(val => {
        this.show = val;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.listener) {
      this.listener.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

To be honnest, this is working fine ! My problem is that I do not find this solution really elegant. I'm pretty sure there is possibly something to do to avoid this token system.
Also, I'm pretty much new to the Observables, and I believe a more elegant solution can be found using these. And as I want to improve my Observable skills, I would love to go in this way

So if you can help me finding a better solution, that would be very helpful. Thanks !

Comment: For a more elegant way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207721/how-to-show-a-loading-spinner-while-waiting-on-an-observable-getting-data-from-a/60222078#60222078. A more complex example using an operator in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769941/ionic-4-correct-way-to-show-loading-no-records-and-data-block/60770597#60770597

Comment: For solution which works with multiple Requests have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475079/how-to-add-to-array-if-no-response-during-1-second